# Getting Error System.InvalidOperationException When Invoke WebService Method

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services

I had Create One WebService..and Create Get Method inside WebService..

My code is

> public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
> {
>
> ```
>     DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
>
>     public WebService () 
>     {
>         //Console.log("Enter");
>         //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
>         //InitializeComponent(); 
>     }
>
>     [WebMethod]
>     public string HelloWorld() {
>         return "Hello World";
>     }
>
>     [WebMethod]
>     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
>     public object Get()
>     {        
>         return db.Countries.ToList();
>     }
> }
> ```

**But When I am Test Web-service at that I am getting following Error..**

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
> XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Country, App_Code.hlnie2jd,
> Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] may not be
> used in this context.    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String
> name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)    at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String
> n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write3_anyType(Object
> o)    at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ObjectSerializer.Serialize(Object
> objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
> Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
> String id)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
> Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
> String id)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
> textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)    at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
> textWriter, Object o)    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse
> response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[]
> returnValues, Stream outputStream)    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
> returnValues)    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

any one having solution please help me

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your method signature has object as return type.

Have a look at this question:
[...may not be used in this context...while serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730238/may-not-be-used-in-this-context-while-serialization)

Comment: **If i am declare method as List<Country>**
`[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public List<Country> Get()
    {        
        return db.Countries.ToList();
    }`
**Then also same Error...**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return neither list, nor object types from the service.

But you can return arrays:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Country[] Get()
    {
        // get you data
        return data.ToArray();
    }
```